# does spring security jars have dependency on java version?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I was using spring secuirty jars with version 4.1.0 and spring version 4.2.6 with java 7 and the code was working fine.
But when I shifted my code to java 1.6(due to some internal policies) and it stopped working. the frontEnd code is not even hitting the middle tier. 
Also I am not getting any compile time or startup error in logs?
Any help around this, is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think it's should be ok with java 6. See this blog post https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8

Comment: We're using pretty much the same stack with no issues. Turning on DEBUG logging for SS normally helps a lot.

Comment: I am not getting any error in console or startup logs. but when I see developer tools console I am getting below error :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Also @PaulNUK , please help how to enable SS logs ?
Thanks ..!!